# Reading Cookie manager Variables in Jmeter

Tags: variables, cookies, jmeter

I have imported Cookie values from getcookies.txt into Http cookie manager of jmeter It has all list of cookie values. I want to export token value from the imported cookies value and passed into http header manager of corresponding call.

I have set the cookiemanager.set.value=true in jmeter.properties file and passed the token=${COOKIE_X-token} but it is passing ${COOKIE_X-token} same value.

please suggest the solution to over come this issue in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've set the [wrong property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous), it should be:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. You've set it in the wrong place, any customization should go to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter).

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

Comment: @Dmitir T                                                                                                                                  
 1 CookieManager.save.cookies=true   --- This change I need to set in user.properties file ?     2 token=${COOKIE_X-token} --this variable can take cookie value of manually imported form getcookies.txt file value?